CRM365 unable to set email message to field using DynamicsCRM2011 connector
I am trying to create/update an email message in CRM365. I have tried the following code
// Establish connection
$service = new DynamicsCRM2011_Connector($serverUrl,$organizationUniqueName, $username, $password);

// Create email message entity
$emailMessage = new DynamicsCRM2011_Entity('email');
$emailMessage->set('subject', 'Test Email');
$emailMessage->set('description', 'This is a test email message.');

// Set sender
$from = new DynamicsCRM2011_EntityReference('systemuser');
$from->id = '{sender_systemuser_id}'; // Replace with actual sender system user ID
$emailMessage->set('from', $from);

// Set To (PartyList)
$toPartyList = array();

// Add contact to the PartyList
$contactRef = new DynamicsCRM2011_EntityReference('contact');
$contactRef->id = '{recipient_contact_id}'; // Replace with actual recipient contact ID
$toPartyList[] = $contactRef;

// Add system user to the PartyList
$userRef = new DynamicsCRM2011_EntityReference('systemuser');
$userRef->id = '{recipient_systemuser_id}'; // Replace with actual recipient system user ID
$toPartyList[] = $userRef;

// Set To field
$emailMessage->set('to', $toPartyList);

// Save email message
$emailMessageId = $service->create($emailMessage);

if ($emailMessageId) {
    echo "Email message created successfully with ID: $emailMessageId";
} else {
    echo "Failed to create email message.";
}

It's set the subject and description but I am unable to set to and from partylist.

I am using https://github.com/Rocketeer007/php-dynamics-crm-2011
